# I want to create a loop that will create a table out of user input data from a prompt

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to input both 'part ID' and 'quantity' through prompt and have those values added to a table; which I've managed so far. After that, I want to add another row below the first one using the same method resulting in 2 rows with different values etc.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<!--CREATE AND POPULATE TABLE -->
<body onload="partID(); qty()">
    <table id="resultsTable" border=".5px" class="results">
        <tr><th>Part ID</th><th>Quantity</th>
        <tr>
            <td id="partID">Part ID</td>
            <td id="qty">Quantity</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<br>

<!-- I want this f('createTable') to bring the prompt back and append to existing table onclick, if that makes sense --> 
<button onclick="createTable()">Add Another Part</button>

</body>

<!-- LOCAL SCRIPTS -->
<script>
    function partID(){
        var partID = prompt("Enter part ID:");
        var x = document.getElementById('partID');
        x.innerHTML = partID;
    }

    function qty(){
        var qty = prompt("Enter Quantity:");
        var y = document.getElementById('qty');
        y.innerHTML = qty;
    }

</script>
</html>
```

I can get it to work once around but I'm not sure how to repeat it for a new row and without losing previous data.

Comment: Why not using onclick on each row instead of onload on the body? I am not sure what you are trying to do here at all

Comment: I want the users to see as little of this page as possible. I have a homepage that redirects to this page so I added the onload into the body tag so the very first row in the table is added asap. Then there is a button underneath that row that will bring back up the prompt and ask for a second row of td. I just cant figure out how to append the table without deleting the previous row or creating the table beforehand. I'm hoping there is a way to append the table dynamically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is append data to the table, right now you are setting the values of individual cells instead of just appending them to the already existing ones.
JavaScript has a neat little shortcut for appending (just like many other languages) which is `+=`, basically `var myVar = 'Foo'; myVar += 'Bar';` is equal to `var myVar = 'Foo'; myVar = myVar + 'Bar';`

```js
function add() {
  //prompt the user with boxes for the ID and quantity
  var partID = prompt("Enter part ID:");
  var qty = prompt("Enter Quantity:");
  //generate the HTML for a new table row and insert the given values
  var table_html = "<tr><td>" + partID + "</td><td>" + qty + "</td></tr>";
  //append the HTML to the already existing HTML in the table
  document.getElementById('resultsTable').innerHTML += table_html;
}
```

```css
/*I dont like default buttons*/
button {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 0px;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload="add();">
    <!-- instead of onload use a button so the user can repeat the action multiple times -->
    <button onclick="add();">Add part</button>
    <hr>
    <table id="resultsTable" border=".5px" class="results">
      <tr>
        <th>Part ID</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps, if you need further explanation about the code just leave a comment.

Good luck.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Joeri. That worked. I just wasn't sure why I couldn't use a similar function and STILL have onload inside <body> but I can always deal with that later.. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but with this function it should work when you use onload, just make sure the function is declared before you reference the onload. In your example the <script> tag is after the <body> tag so maybe (?) that was what caused the problem

Comment: I want the very first row to be created before the page loads because this page is redirecting from a different page.. I'm able to do both now the <body onload> and <button = onclick>. I was mostly having trouble with the function for the button... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to be able to add a new row to the `<table>`. For this, you probably want to use a button.

```
<button onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>
```

Then you can add a row using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/insertAdjacentHTML) :

```
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById('resultsTable');
  var partID = prompt("Enter part ID:");
  var qty = prompt("Enter Quantity:");
  table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<tr><td>" + partID + "</td><td>" + qty + "</td></tr>")
}
```

*Using `insertAdjacentHTML` is safer and more efficient than replacing the whole table `innerHTML`.*